there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x_n\neq 0$ for all $n \geq n_0$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x_n}\right)_{n \geq n_0}=\frac{1}{L}$.
I am struggling with the following proof.
(Note that the naturals numbers are defined as $\mathbb{N}:=\{0,1,2,3,...\}\ here.)$

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a convergent sequence of real numbers
with limit $L\neq 0$. Prove that there exists $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such
that $x_n\neq 0$ for all $n \geq n_0$, and
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x_n}\right)_{n \geq
> n_0}=\frac{1}{L}$.

I am particularly confused about how to not only prove the statement but also write it in a structured and clear manner. As I am new to proof-writing, I still struggle significantly with epsilon proofs.
What confuses me the most in this problem is the "$n \geq n_0$" condition. I find it difficult to visualize what exactly I am supposed to prove in this case, unlike in a standard limit proof, where I can often rely on a graphical interpretation.
This is what I have so far:
I tried to dissemble my proof In two parts: proving first that there exists such $n_0$ and then second that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x_n}\right)_{n \geq n_0}=\frac{1}{L}$.
I wasn't even able to begin the first part because I do not understand.
The second part I have started this:
Let $\epsilon<0,\ \forall n\geq n_0>N\in\mathbb{N}$
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{x_n}-\frac{1}{L}\right|&=\left|\frac{x_n-L}{x_n\cdot L}\right|\\
&=\frac{|x_n-L|}{|x_n\cdot L|}\\
&<\frac{x_n-L}{x_n\cdot \frac{|L|}{2}}\\
&<\frac{\frac{|L|^2}{2}\epsilon}{\frac{|L|^2}{2}}=\epsilon
\end{align*}
I would appreciate any help because I have been on this proof for days now without progress

First note that $(x_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ converges to $L$ and since $L \neq 0$, and so $|L| \neq 0$, so then there exists an $N_1 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - L| < \frac{|L|}{2}$ for all $n \geq N_1$. By the reverse triangle inequality, this implies that
\begin{equation*}
|L| - |x_n| < \frac{|L|}{2}
\end{equation*}
for all $n \geq N_1$, and so $\frac{|L|}{2} < |x_n|$ for all $n \geq N_1$. Then $\frac{1}{|x_n|} \leq \frac{2}{|L|}$ for all $n \geq N_1$.
Now let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Since $|L| \neq 0$ and $(x_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ converges to $L$, there exists an $N_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_n - L| < \frac{|L|^2}{2}\varepsilon$ for all $n \geq N_2$. Put $n_0 = \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ and hence for all $n \geq n_0$, we have that
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{1}{x_n} - \frac{1}{L}\right| &= \left|\frac{L - x_n}{x_nL}\right| \\
&= |L - x_n|\frac{1}{|x_n|}\frac{1}{|L|} \\
&< \left(\frac{|L|^2}{2}\varepsilon\right)\left(\frac{2}{|L|}\right)\left(\frac{1}{|L|}\right) \\
&= \varepsilon
\end{align*}
Therefore, as $\varepsilon > 0$ was arbitrary, $\left(\frac{1}{x_n}\right)$ converges to $\frac{1}{L}$.
